# How to make an URL to work with .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, url, web

I think this is not a duplicate question because i didnt find it here. Here goes my doubt.
I have this link:

> http://hellow/hellowWorld1/hellowWorld2/aps.php?c=Bank&nom=WhatEver&n=10101010

And the Result i would like to be this one:

> http://hello/hellowWorld1/hellowWorld2/Bank/WhatEver

i tried something in .htacces but it gives me a 500 Internal Error!

And the other doubt is that i have inside my file.php $_GET to those variables. So here goes my question. Those $_GET will still get the variables from my url or not?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error 500 means you have a problem with your configuration, in this case with your `.htaccess` file. Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: "i tried something in .htacces but it gives me a 500 Internal Error: " can you post what you tried?

Comment: @ anubhava i would like to avoid this only if  my $_GET variables will still get that variable from the url. Is the first time when i am building this so sorry for being a Kiddie

Comment: @Starkeen : <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . ^(+.)/(+.)/(+.)  aps.php?c=$1&nom=$2&n=$3
</IfModule>
Something like this I dont hace the code right in front of me but was something like this.

Comment: @anubhava my .htacces is the same directory as my index.php and the aps.php is in the view directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=([^\&]*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} nom=([^\&]*)
RewriteRule aps.php$ %1/%2? [NC]
```

Tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

The 2 `RewriteCond` lines detect the query string and allow for a back-substitution with `%1` and `%2` in the RewriteRule.

The `?` at the end of the `RewriteRule` is an empty query string so that the GET variables won't be passed through.

`[NC]` means case insensitive comparisons.

Comment: Tanks man works like a charm! I have a final question my $_GET["n"] from my php  will still receive those variables?

Comment: No it wont. To do that you need to remove the ? from the RewriteRule

Comment: Test with and without to be sure though.